# SyntaxError a la hora de utilizar pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Sistema operativo Windows 10 64bits. Tengo instalada la versión 3.10.1 de Python. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He instalado correctamente pygame a través de `pip install` y lo he comprobado a través de mcd y todo está en orden. Cuando compruebo pygame en el IDLE así:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode()
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\pygame3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "D:\Python\pygame.py", line 1
    Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

He reinstalado python y pygame y sigue el error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese error?

Comment: lo más probable es que sea por la versión de python, quizá pygame aún no tiene soporte para esa versión, lo uso en winn 10 64 bits con python 3.9.5 y anda muy bien

Comment: Examina con un editor el contenido del fichero `D:\Python\pygame.py` Por alguna misteriosa razón parece que en lugar de contener codigo python contiene otra cosa (parece que haya sido creado con el comando `python > pygame.py`). Ademas ese fichero no debería estar ahi (no deberías crear ficheros con el mismo nombre que paquetes python). Borralo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error proviene del nombre del script, nunca hay que usar el nombre **pygame** para ningún script porque cuando hagas la importación se confunde la biblioteca instalada con una biblioteca personal. Intenta usar un nombre distinto.

Por cierto python tiene mayor preferencia para las bibliotecas personales sobre las bibliotecas instaladas, eso quiere decir que si tienes un script con un nombre de una biblioteca existente se importará ese script en lugar de la biblioteca instalada, eso produce errores difíciles de rastrear.

Comment: No es que tenga preferencia por las bibliotecas personales, es solo que sigue un cierto orden a la hora de mirar en qué carpetas ha de buscar un módulo cuando es importado. La primera carpeta en la que mirará (por defecto, a menos que cambies el PYTHONPATH) será la misma en la que se esté ejecutando el script actual. Por eso, si tienes un módulo en esa carpeta con el mismo nombre que otro módulo python, importará el tuyo en lugar del suyo, porque lo encuentra antes. Si el tuyo está en otra carpeta no sucederá esto.